# Custom List View with checkbox, selects other child elements which are not visible

Tags: android, listview, select, checkbox

I have a custom list view with custom array adapter. I am using list view for multi rows selection. But when I select the rows of visible children, and scroll up/down the list view, other child which appear they are also selected.

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(convertView == null)
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.addbill_row,parent,false);

        initUI(convertView);

        assignValues(position);

        cbAddBillSelected.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(isChecked)
                {
                    Data.arrlstSelectedUsers.get(position).isChecked = true;



                }
                else
                {
                    Data.arrlstSelectedUsers.get(position).isChecked = false;


                }


            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }
```

Attaching screen shots also. No idea why this is happening , I have another work around by saving selected item in shared preferences, but its a long solution. 
Looking for a better solution.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have recycled views in the list. You should reset the checked state for both new and recycled views in `getView()`, likely this should be in your `initUI()` you didn't post in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed Vogella List View tutorial, and it worked like a charm. Using Tags.

[Vogella List View](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use built-in `ListView` with `Checkbox` layout? `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice` will work for you.

Comment: I need to use customer array adapter, as I am using custom object of "Users" for populating my list view.

Comment: what is the structure of each item on your ListView? As i saw from screenshot it's just a single text + checkbox, so you can pass a String array of User's necessary information to the adapter of this built-in layout?

Comment: okies,let me try it, I am overriding the toString() method to return UserName only, in this way my List View will show user names.

Answer (score 0):

It is something in the assign values function. you must also assign the check box in it. If this not enough as an answer plz modify your question and include the assign values function code to it. I will modify it.

This happen when convertView is not null. it gets you a used view. that's how this method work "getView". so you must modify every ui element everytime when convertView is not null.